# Async read a subprocess stdin/stderr results into strings in Vala

Tags: asynchronous, vala

I try to read stdin and stderr into strings from a subprocess. I request the pipe and the exit code is 0 (success) but the strings are empty.

```cs
string errStr = "";
string outStr = "";

string[] cmd = {
    "grep",
    "--help"
};

var grep = new Subprocess.newv(cmd, 
    SubprocessFlags.STDOUT_PIPE|SubprocessFlags.STDERR_PIPE);
yield grep.wait_async();

int exit_code = grep.get_exit_status();

size_t bytes;
yield grep.get_stderr_pipe().read_all_async(errStr.data, 0, null, out bytes);
yield grep.get_stdout_pipe().read_all_async(outStr.data, 0, null, out bytes);
```

Why is nothing read from the InputStream to strings (outStr, errStr)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is not working as `string.data` is not meant to be used this way. Instead a `DataInputStream` should be used that provides functions like `read_line()`. See [details here](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.DataInputStream.html).

```cs
var dis = new DataInputStream(grep.get_stdout_pipe());
```

In my case I also need control over the environment of the subprocess so in then you have to use`GLib.Process.spawn_async_with_pipes()` instead of `Subprocess`. See [details here](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Process.spawn_async_with_pipes.html).

Comment: If you want to communicate with a love lived subprocess then look at [GLib.Subprocess.communicate_async](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.Subprocess.communicate_async.html)